# Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I set up my app to generate pre-signed URLs for access to S3 media (so that I can set the files to be private, unless accessed via a logged in user) then would I be right in saying that, if someone has access to the URL (within the expiry time) they can see the file, despite it being "private"?

So if someone was to send the URL to someone else, then it's not really private any more.

I guess there's no other way but this just seems odd to me.

Comment: Then you should do something like passing header values with url (For the logged in user) where they can see the url and share to someone. But the server won't provide image until it has the header values.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

That would still be a separate user requesting content. For a separate user, the certificate would not longer be valid.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html

Comment: When I say "logged in user", I mean "logged in to my website". I'm not talking about S3 users. So if someone that is logged in to my site clicks on a link to a private document, they get a signed URL using my S3 credentials which, in theory, they could forward to a friend (who isn't logged in to my site).

Comment: Your site needs to verify access to the object with a header. Another user given the URL without the proper header value will no longer have a valid signature and will not be able to access the object.

Comment: Ah, of course - so I hide the S3 files behind a URL on my site, with a permission check for that URL to stop unauthenticated access. Got it. I think. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct, @EFeit. I'm not sure what you're thinking, because neither S3 nor CloudFront signed URLs for `GET` requests are going to result in the service checking any headers.

Comment: Please include the code and instructions with your answer. Please avoid sending folks off-site. Once you have enough reputation you will be able to ptovide comments with information like this.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are correct that a signed URL can be "shared" because it is valid until it expires (or until the credentials that signed it expire or are otherwise invalidated, whichever comes first).

One common solution is for your application to generate signed URLs as the page is being rendered, using very short expiration times.

Another is for the link to the secured content to actually be a link back to the application, which verifies the user's authority to access the object, and then returns an HTTP redirect to a freshly-generated signed URL with a short expiration time (e.g. 5 seconds).

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/...?X-Amz-...
```

Signed URLs cannot be tampered with using currently feasible compute capabilities, so it is impractical to the point of impossibility for a signed URL to be modified by a malicious user.

Note also that a signed URL (for either S3 or CloudFront) only needs to be not-yet-expired when the download *starts*.  The time required for the download to actually *finish* can be arbitrarily long, and the download will not be interrupted.

There is no ready-made service for the following option, but using a combination of CloudFront Lambda@Edge triggers and DynamoDB, it is possible to create a genuinely single-use URL, which consists of a randomly generated "token" stored in the Dynamo table and associated with the target object.  When the URL is accessed, you use a DynamoDB conditional update in the Lambda trigger to update the (e.g.) "view_count" value from 0 to 1.  If the token isn't in the table or the view count isn't 0, the conditional update fails, so access is denied; otherwise CloudFront allows the request to proceed -- exactly once.  CloudFront accesses the S3 content using an Origin Access Identity, which all happens behind the scenes, so nothing related to the actual authentication of the request between CloudFront and S3 is accessible to the user.  (For cryptographic-quality random token generation, you can also use KMS's [`GenerateRandom`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/kms-2014-11-01/GenerateRandom) API action.)

There are a number of alternative approaches, including other uses of Lambda@Edge triggers to do things like inspect a request for an application-provided cookie and then querying the application server to authenticate the user.

CloudFront also supports signed cookies that it parses and interprets, itself, but these provide wildcard-based access to all your assets matching a specific URL and path (e.g. `/images/*`) and there is nothing to prevent a user from sharing their cookies, so these are probably not useful for your use case.

CloudFront signed URLs do support the option of allowing access only if the signed URL is used from a specific source (client) IP address, but this has potential problems in there is no assurance that a 1:1 correlation exists between users and IP addresses.  Many users can be behind the same address (particularly in corporate network environments) or a single user's address can change at any moment.

The complexity of the possible implementations varies wildly, and what you need depends in part on how secure you need for your content to be.  In many cases, more extreme solutions accomplish little more than discouraging honest users, because the user can still *download* the resource and share it via other means.